# ¿Como sacar la direccion local por ejemplo 192.168.1.47/Openbravo?

Tags: xampp, tomcat, ip

Miren me explico mejor, Instale un ERP de Openbravo, lo que sucede es que solo para entrar de manera local en la misma computadora entro por localhost:8080/Openbravo, entonces, si quiero conectarme de otra computadora de manera local por el url de localhost no puedo, yo eh trabajado con xampp y xampp tiene esa opción de poder entrar por la ip local y así desde otra computadoras, de ante mano espero me puedan dar una solución o alguien de ustedes sepan o si puedo instalar OPENBRAVO directamente en xampp aunque por lo que estuve investigando no se puede pero igual espero su apoyo, soy nuevo en esto de los ERP'S.

Comment: Usualmente puedes **ver la información de la conexión**. En ubuntu p.ej. te aparece un bloque **IPv4** y en él encuentras la Dirección IP. ej: 192.168.0.5 (mi caso) y desde otros equipos conectados a la misma red usas `http://192.168.0.5:8080/Openbravo/` Fijate que uso el puerto y tu directorio (la dirección será otra en tu caso, pero muy parecida)

Comment: Usando la IP pública de la máquina

Comment: O la IP privada, dependiendo del set up.... o la IP del router, si hay NAT configurado... aquí las opciones son bastante variadas.... y eso sin entrar a hablar de nombres de dominio. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Si el servidor es un linux, podrías ver esa información corriendo este comando:

```
ip addr show
```

Dependiendo de la distro/setup el comando lo vas a poder correr como un osuario normal, o necesitar correrlo como root o con sudo.

Si es un windows, supongo que con algo como ipconfig, que no tengo ni idea de si todavia se puede usar en Windows.